# Understanding how C struct aliases are compiled

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to understand how structure aliases get compiled into a binary, especially when there is a modifier in front of it. I notice that having an alias both with and without a * result in different binaries (checked using shasum). For example, given the following structure:

```
typedef struct __foobar {
    int a;
    int b;
} *pfoobar_t, foobar_t;
```

how are the following variable declarations different from the C standard and a compiler perspective:

```
const pfoobar_t my_var;
const foobar_t *my_var;
foobar_t const *my_var;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide two complete examples to illustrate the difference you are asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between

```
const pfoobar_t my_var;
```

and

```
const foobar_t *my_var;
```

is that the first one declares `my_var` itself to be `const`, whereas the second one declares `my_var` to be a pointer to a `const` object.

The first one is incorrect other than in file scope because `const` variables must be initialised (since they cannot be modified). At file scope, the variable will be initialised to `NULL`; since it cannot be modified, any use of it can be substituted with a constant `NULL`.

In the second case, the variable itself can be modified, so it doesn't matter that it is uninitialised. However, once it is made to point to some `struct __foobar`, modification of that object using the pointer is not allowed.

The third declaration is identical to the second. The first one could have been written

```
 foobar_t *const my_var;
```

By the way, identifiers starting with two underscores (such as `struct __foobar`) are reserved for use by the standard library (or other implementation details) and should not be used in a program.

Comment: So if the first and third are identical, why are the binaries that are produced have different shasums?

Comment: @slagathor. I said that the second and third are identical. The first is different.

Comment: That you did. My mistake. Read to fast, and mixed up the last few comments you had.

Answer (score 1):

A struct is simply a compacted portion of memory. Example, `int a; int b;` on a 32-bits architecture, will result in an 8-bytes structure (2 x 4 bytes).

Unaligned structures (eg: 9 bytes) are possible, though when allocated (on the stack for example) the memory area allocated will be aligned (12 bytes, `sub $esp, 12`).

You can see that the compiler reacts differently, and that those assignments differ notably by the use of the `const` directive:

Given the following structure:

```
typedef struct __foobar {
    int a;
    int b;
} *pfoobar_t, foobar_t;
```

You try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  foobar_t var;
  const pfoobar_t my_var = &var;
  my_var->a = 3;
  printf("%d\n", my_var->a);
}
```

It compiles and runs without issue. Now change the code for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  foobar_t var;
  const foobar_t *my_var;
  my_var->a = 3;
  printf("%d\n", my_var->a);
}
```

It won't compile:

```
const.c: In function ‘main’:
const.c:13:3: error: assignment of member ‘a’ in read-only object
   my_var->a = 3;
```

Static objects are stored in a dedicated portion of a binary and thus your different declarations change the shape of the ELF format.